# Orientation of polygon in FME?

Tags: fme-form

how can i identify orientation of a building in reference to another rectangle (eg building located  at North side or south side in reference with campus).

in FME there is a way to find out?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  You had a tag for ArcGIS (presumably Desktop) but only mention FME in your question, so I replaced it with that.

Comment: The orientor will help http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/orientor.htm depending on your source data as orientation is different in different data formats.

Comment: @Mapperz - the *Orientor* doesn't do anything apart from change something between left handed and right handed. *OrientationExtractor* is just as unhelpful. Were the problem just one of rotation the PolylineAnalyzer (in the FME Store) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Note: It's not the Orientation you want, but the relative position within the campus.

The answer is: Yes but it's difficult. Below is a general overview of how you might do it.

1. Take the campus polygon and run it through the `BoundingBoxReplacer`. You don't need it as an Oriented Bounding Box if you only want North/South/East/West. (Orientation will make stage 3 much harder)
2. Run this bounds polygon through a Chopper, chopping by Vertex and keeping a maximum of 2 vertices. The result of this is that you'll have four lines, one on each side.
3. You now need to set each "side" to being a point of the compass. This is the tricky bit, I'd suggest some combination of a `BoundsExtractor` on the original polygon, `CoordinateExtractors` and `Testers`. (i.e. if the two coordinates of this line are the same as minx and both miny and maxy of the polygon, then this is the west (left) line). Use an AttributeCreator to set the value for each line.

That's the processing for the campus complete.

4. You need to ensure you're only dealing with buildings inside the campus. Either a `SpatialRelator` (better if there are multiple campuses) or a `SpatialFilter` will do that.

Now to bring them together.

5. Use a `NeighborFinder` to check each of the buildings within the campus (using group by) against the four lines of the campus bounds. This will find which of the four lines is closest and give it the attributes of that line (i.e. East, North, South, West). Be sure to set Attribute Accumulation on it.

The above will work best with a square campus. With your campus above (a rectangle) you'd probably have to give some sort of weighting to the shorter lines (north/south) otherwise everything will join to the east/west (side) lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility comes to mind which will work through the problem of non-square campuses that appears in my first answer.

1. Feed your campus polygon into the `Chopper`, and again set to keep only 2 vertices.
2. Turn these vertices into points that are half-way down the line. I'd suggest using the `Snipper` for *Distance (Percentage)* and 50%.

You now have a set of points, each is half-way down one of the sides of the campus.

3. As in stage 3 of the other answer, figure out which point is North/East/South/West.
4. Feed these points into the `VoronoiCellGenerator`. *Site Name Attribute* needs to be unique for each feature, so use a concatenated campus_id with the east/west/north/south containing attribute. *Azimuth Attribute* I pointed to an attribute with a value of 1, and used values of 1 for the other parameters as well.
   You want the VoronoiPolygons output port.
   I'm not that familiar with this transformer so don't know what will produce the test results. Experiment!
5. Use a `Clipper` to clip the voronois to the campus extent.

You now have the campus split neatly into appropriate sections, looking something like this for your example:

[image]

6. Use a `SpatialFilter`/`SpatialRelator` to test each building and see which voronoid it's best related to. Where a building sits on a voronoid junction you may want to start measuring overlapping percentages (`AreaOnAreaCalculator` and all that) to determine whether something is North or East. Or, a better option may be to use that information to say that it's neither North nor East, but in fact North East (an unexpected bonus of this method).

This method should get better results than the other one.